# Sequel::Model paginate/each_page only returns first page of data

Tags: ruby, sequel

I know I am very close to getting this code working, but must be missing something simple.

I have a series of teradata and oracle tables which I've abstracted using sequel::model. Ive loaded the pagination extension to the database. I can get a dataset returned but no matter what I do, I can't get it to give me anything other than the first page.

Here is an example of how Ive abstracted the tables.

```
module MyDB
   class MyTable< Sequel::Model(tera_db["#{$env[:my_db]}__my_table".to_sym])
      @factory_name = :my_factory
      set_primary_key [:my_primary_key]
      @typecast_on_assignment = false
   end
end
```

Here is how Ive implemented some test code around each_page

```
MyDB::MyTable.order(:my_primary_key).each_page(1000) do |page|
   p page.current_page_record_count
   p page.count
   p page.first
end
```

There are 87,675 records in the dataset. The last two iterations output from this loop are:

1000

1000

values={:key1=>12345, :key2=>14.58, :key3=> 155.44}

675

1000

values={:key1=>12345, :key2=>14.58, :key3=> 155.44}

So...the proper number of pages are being created. And the underlying count of paged records is correct. But when I try to get the actual values in the page, it only gets the records from the first page including the record count.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `page.first` is removing the offset from the dataset?  I can't recreate your results.  It's possible the issue is in the teradata adapter (which is external adapter not part of Sequel itself).  You may want to try `page.from_self.first`, or `page.limit(1).all[0]` and see if the results are different, as well as post an SQL log (which you can probably generate using `tera_db.loggers << Logger.new($stdout)`)

Comment: Thanks Jeremy...

The ultimate goal of my attempt at using pagination was to be able to roll through large datasets without loading it all in memory at once. Since I can do that by just using .each on the regular dataset, I don't really have to use paging. I agree that this is likely a problem with the teradata adapter.